# Moviepy swap text mid video

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I want to write text to a video and have it change mid playback, this is what I've tried but it overlays each text on eachother and only displays the text for 5 seconds?

```
def generateVideo(initial_text, secondary_text, tertiary_text):
    text_clip = TextClip(txt=initial_text, color='AntiqueWhite1', font='Arial-Bold', fontsize=100)
    text_clip = text_clip.set_position('center').set_duration(5)

    text_clip_secondary = TextClip(txt=secondary_text, color='AntiqueWhite1', font='Arial-Bold', fontsize=100)
    text_clip_secondary = text_clip_secondary.set_position('center').set_duration(10).cutout(0, 5)

    text_clip_tertiary = TextClip(txt=tertiary_text, color='AntiqueWhite1', font='Arial-Bold', fontsize=100)
    text_clip_tertiary = text_clip_tertiary.set_position('center').set_duration(15).cutout(0, 10)
    
    new_video = ColorClip(size=(1920, 1080), color=(0,0,0), duration=15)
    new_video.fps = 24
    
    new_video = CompositeVideoClip([new_video, text_clip, text_clip_secondary, text_clip_tertiary])

    new_video.write_videofile(codec='mpeg4', filename="test.mp4")
    new_video.close()
```

Anyone see what im doing wrong?

Edit:
I've also tried the appropriate calls to subclip(pos1, pos2), ie

```
text_clip_secondary = text_clip_secondary.set_position('center').set_duration(15).subclip(5, 10)
```

With the same results

Answer (score 1):

It looks like both ***cutout() and subclip() aren't able to be used with TextClip()*** so I dug around in the library a bit and figured out that ***set_start()*** seems to work

Ex:

```
text_clip = TextClip(txt=initial_text, color='AntiqueWhite1', font='Arial-Bold', fontsize=100)
text_clip = text_clip.set_position('center').set_duration(5)

text_clip_secondary = TextClip(txt=secondary_text, color='AntiqueWhite1', font='Arial-Bold', fontsize=100)
text_clip_secondary = text_clip_secondary.set_position('center').set_duration(5).set_start(5)
```

This might be intentional but I dont see how as TextClip is a child class of VideoClip, perhaps it will be fixed in later revisions